# golang read hosts entry or just read it in as a file

Tags: go

I need to read an entry from the host file on Linux.

I have looked at `"net"`

```
fmt.Println("net host file entry:")
fmt.Println(net.LookupIP("AAA"))
fmt.Println(net.LookupAddr("BBB"))
fmt.Println(net.LookupHost("CCC"))
```

net.LookupIP("AAA") gives me: `no such host`. 


Though I can see the entry if I do `getent hosts` from the terminal.

I just need to read the ip address?

Note: I am running this within a docker container and the etc/hosts file do contain the entry - I can read it from a shell script but not from go.
In docker you can link containers and this will give you an entry in the hosts file.

Or should I just read it in as a file?

Comment: Do you specifically need to read and entry in `/etc/hosts`, or just resolve an address that might be in `/etc/hosts`? Does `net.LookupIP` not do what you want?

Comment: net.LookupIP("AAA") gives me: no such host. I can see the entry if I call "getent hosts" from the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, yes I just need to read the ip address?

Comment: What version of Go are you using? Are the values actually in the /etc/hosts file, or are they being pulled from somewhere else via nsswitch?

Comment: go version go1.5.1 linux/amd64. Hmm, good question I am running within a docker container.

Comment: Look at the `/etc/hosts` in your docker container, not the system `/etc/hosts`. If this didn't work, you wouldn't ever be able to use `localhost` as a hostname.

Comment: BTW, you should read the relevant docs: https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#managing-etc-hosts

Comment: Try using --net=host when running your docker container - might resolve the issue by allowing access to the host network

Comment: I can read it from a shell script but not from go?

Comment: `LookupHost` does indeed work. Thanks and sorry for using your time. I will close this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just read the file...

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

and then

```
dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts")
fmt.Print(string(dat))
```

you can parse the result of course